# Change in Modelmapper TypeResolver from release 0.6.3 to 2.3.2

Tags: java, modelmapper

Currently code is using 0.6.3 version of modelmapper dependency for java. It is using TypeResolver for some types. We want to upgrade this library to latest version of 2.3.2. This latest version doesn't contain TypeResolver class. Whats the alternative for this class? Currently my code looks like:

```
Class<?>[] args = TypeResolver.resolveArguments(B.class, A.class);
```

I tried using ModelMapper.map(Source, Destination) but it gives runtime error.

Comment: Did you try mapping between an object and a class ? ```OrderDTO orderDTO = modelMapper.map(order, OrderDTO.class);```

Comment: @AliBenZarrouk That is different case, existing TypeResolver works on classes